# How to create Invite Email when using New-AzStaticWebAppUserRoleInvitationLink

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, role-base-authorization

I have a few thousand users in my Active Directory. I'm assigning Roles to restrict path access to Azure Static Web Apps. We don't want to manually assign roles so we're creating a Powershell script that will create an invite and assign the role.

I execute the following command to invite and assign a role to a single user:

```
PS C:\Installers> New-AzStaticWebAppUserRoleInvitationLink -SubscriptionId <SubscriptionId> -ResourceGroupName <SecureStaticSiteResourceGroupName> -Name SecureStaticSiteName -Domain <SecureStaticSiteName>.azurestaticapps.net -Provider 'azure' -UserDetail 'test@test.com' -Role 'contributor' -NumHoursToExpiration 72
```

Here's what I get as a result

```
Kind Name                                 ResourceGroupName
---- ----                                 -----------------
     99x99999-99xx-9x99-9x99-99x9xxxx9xxx SecureStaticSiteResourceGroupName
```

I thought I would be able to script the email using Powershell but I'm confused how I can generate a similar email like the one generated when creating an invite thru the Role Management User Interface?

Here's what gets generated thru the UI:

```
https://<SecureStaticSiteName>.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/invitations/accept?provider=aad&userDetails=test%40test.com&roles=contributor&se=2022-06-15T17%3A41%3A15Z&sig=b91pyHaosUQ%2F5zlMZgux0hUiO2Soso74UYYTvAOhVjmh5byyU9VjEssBOV8cXLg%2BYVfTsqmHKtOe8SjYehza00BfuJGUFFdpQpy%2F7zcuovVP5krtHHPimzecB4Vxwfy1HHjdynGaf7hBxhJynGK6Du2827iPE3z%2BSMPJ48X7Z7V%2BDG6nDkyjjk%2FfAxT5udXzDuNi%2BXik8C%2BRoKnxi3ZlQg%3D%3D
```

The signature in the generated url is what's throwing me off here. Any idea how I can generate that and send the email off to the user?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.